# Pandas dataframe: Pivoting multiple date columns with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe I need to pivot but can't figure out how. I have multiple year columns with multiple values

Example data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqXoU.png)

Desired result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsXyE.png)

Comment: Please dont post images. Paste everything as code.

Comment: Please look at this example: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html and try to post data as code. This will help others  to copy and reproduce your requirement.